# Difference between Exchange Web Services of Exchange server 2007 and Exchange Server 2010

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchange-server-2010

I am working on one client issue related to Exchange server. and so I am looking for the exact difference between the above mentioned EWS. 
I had WSDL for two Exchange web service one of Exchange server at our end, and another is from our client Exchange server. When I compared both of them, i found following difference.

Client Side WSDL :

```
     <wsdl:operation name="CreateItem">
     <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/CreateItem" />
     - <wsdl:input>
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" part="Impersonation" use="literal" />
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" part="S2SAuth" use="literal" />
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" part="MailboxCulture" use="literal" />
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" part="RequestVersion" use="literal" />
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" part="TimeZoneContext" use="literal" />
      <soap:body parts="request" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
```

WSDL at OUR END:

```
      </wsdl:operation> -<wsdl:operation name="CreateItem">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/CreateItem"/>
     -<wsdl:input>
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" use="literal" part="Impersonation"/>
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" use="literal" part="S2SAuth"/>
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" use="literal" part="MailboxCulture"/>
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" use="literal" part="RequestVersion"/>
      <soap:body use="literal" parts="request"/>
      </wsdl:input>
```

---

```
      <soap:header message="tns:CreateItemSoapIn" part="TimeZoneContext" use="literal" />
```

This is the line which is extra in their WSDL. Can any one explain,For what purpose this can be?

And how can I determine the version of EWS?

Comment: Can I determine server version info from WSDL only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Exchange 2010, [TimeZones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633707%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) can be established for Appointment items relative to a global timezone when connecting to the service as opposed to setting it for each appointment item as you must do in Exchange 2007.

You can determine the Server version of EWS by observing the [ServerVersionInfo element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633705%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx) in the SOAP header.